# Registering new login Information Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hi I'd like to have new users register their name and password and have it pushed into the users array. It works in plain Javascript, but for some reason my Angular JS won't.

HERES THE ANGULAR JS

```
var users = [
    {
      username: 'Regie',
      password: 'Tano'
    },
    {
      username: 'Jacob',
      password: 'Minshall'
    },
    {
      username: 'Greg',
      password: 'Mayer'
    }
  ]

app.controller("logIn", function($scope){


  $scope.log = function(){

    //Get Values of Inputs for username and password
    var username= document.getElementById('username').value
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value

    //Loop through users to check if username and password are correct.
    for(i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
      if(username == users[i].username && password == users[i].password){
        alert('That Username or Password is already taken')
      }
    }
  }
});

//REGISTER USER**********
app.controller("registerUser", function($scope){

$scope.place = function(){

  var registerName = document.getElementById('registerName').value
  var registerPass = document.getElementById('registerPass').value
  var newUser = {
    username: registerName,
    password: registerPass
  }

 users.push(newUser)
 console.log(users)

}
});
```

HERE'S THE HTML

```
  <body ng-app='myApp'>

    <form id='form' ng-controller='logIn'>
      <h1>Log In</h1>
      <input type="text" id="username"  placeholder="Enter Username" />
      <input type="password" id="password"placeholder="Enter Password" />
      <button id="button" type="button" ng-click='log()'>Click This</button>
    </form>

    <form id='form2' ng-controller='registerUser'>
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <input type='text' id='registerName' placeholder='Enter Username'/>
    <input type='password' id='registerPass' placeholder='Enter Password'/>
    <button id='registerButton' type='button' ng-click='place()'>Register</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: To start... in the angular world don't do: document.getElementById('registerName').value. Instead use directives such as ng-model: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel.

Comment: is there errors in the console? what is the value of users when you register a user in that console log statement? If possible throw this in a jsfiddle.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 0):

In angular you should not access to the DOM directly, instead use directives as ng-model.
So, you html should be something like this:

```
<body ng-app='myApp'>

    <form id='form' ng-controller='logIn'>
      <h1>Log In</h1>
      <!-- Using ng-model is how you bind data from the view to the controller in AngularJS -->
      <input type='text' ng-model='username' placeholder='Enter Username' />
      <input type='password' ng-model='password' placeholder='Enter Password' />
    <!-- we send the binded data to the function as parameters -->
      <button id="button" type="button" ng-click='log(username, password)'>Click This</button>
    </form>

    <form id='form2' ng-controller='registerUser'>
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <!-- Using ng-model is how you bind data from the view to the controller in AngularJS -->
    <input type='text' ng-model='registerName' placeholder='Enter Username'/>
    <input type='password' ng-model='registerPass' placeholder='Enter Password'/>
    <!-- we send the binded data to the function as parameters -->
    <button id='registerButton' type='button' ng-click='place(registerName, registerPass)'>Register</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

And your controllers:

```
var users = [
    {
      username: 'Regie',
      password: 'Tano'
    },
    {
      username: 'Jacob',
      password: 'Minshall'
    },
    {
      username: 'Greg',
      password: 'Mayer'
    }
  ]

app.controller("logIn", function($scope){
  // This is the username and password in the html
  $scope.username = ''; // ng-model="username"
  $scope.password = ''; // ng-model="password"

  $scope.log = function(username, password){    

    //Loop through users to check if username and password are correct.
    for(i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
      if(username == users[i].username && password == users[i].password){
        alert('That Username or Password is already taken')
      }
    }
  }
});

//REGISTER USER**********
app.controller("registerUser", function($scope){
// This is the registerName and registerPass in the html
$scope.registerName = ''; // ng-model="registerName"
$scope.registerPass = ''; // ng-model="registerPass"

// Instead of read the data in the model, we pass them as parameters. Doing this is better for testing.
$scope.place = function(registerName, registerPass){    

  var newUser = {
    username: registerName,
    password: registerPass
  }

 users.push(newUser)
 console.log(users)

}
});
```